# TOC only with russian letters works incorrectly

Tags: html, r, r-markdown, tableofcontents

When I compile big (~2.8k lines) .Rmd document in HTML I discover that TOC don't work correctly. It sends me to same header from many lines of TOC.

I notice, that if add some english text to header - TOC begin works correct.

Here are two simple files:

- [TOC bad](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/realstarosta/RTry/master/other/TOC-bad.Rmd) - only russian letters in headers; TOC work incorrectly
- [TOC good](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/realstarosta/RTry/master/other/TOC-good.Rmd) - headers with some english  text; TOC work correctly

May be problem in encoding? If yes, then how to fix it?